# Get the Status of Discrete Outputs using PyModbus

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I see a lot of information out there about how to read registers and discrete inputs.  But what about discrete OUTPUTS?  I am able to send commands to turn my "normally open" discrete outputs to "closed" and turn on an LED for proof-of-concept.  What I'd like to do next is find a way to get the status of discrete outputs.  The LED is right in front of me, but most modbus gear is a long way from the server/master.  How can I confirm that the output actually closed?  I don't see a method to read discrete output state?  Looking for something similar to reading discrete inputs:

```
        log.debug("Read discrete inputs")
        rr = await client.read_discrete_inputs(0, 4, unit=UNIT)
        log.debug('First DI is {}'.format(rr.bits[0]))
        log.debug('Second DI is {}'.format(rr.bits[1]))
        log.debug('Third DI is {}'.format(rr.bits[2]))
        log.debug('Fourth DI is {}'.format(rr.bits[3]))
```

Output

```
DEBUG:pymodbus:First DI is False
DEBUG:pymodbus:Second DI is False
DEBUG:pymodbus:Third DI is False
DEBUG:pymodbus:Fourth DI is False
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Modbus Application Protocol Specification](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) details the options for bit access:

| Type | Functions |
| --- | --- |
| Discrete Input | Read Discrete Inputs(02) |
| Coils | Read Coils (01) |
| Coils | Write Single Coil (05) |
| Coils | Write Multiple Coils (15) |

So 'Discrete Inputs' are bit inputs (you can read their state and that's it). 'Coils' are bit outputs with functions to read (get current state), set one and set multiple values. Pymodbus provides access to these functions through:

- [read_coils](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.client.html#pymodbus.client.common.ModbusClientMixin.read_coils)
- [write_coil](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.client.html#pymodbus.client.common.ModbusClientMixin.write_coil)
- [write_coils](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.client.html#pymodbus.client.common.ModbusClientMixin.write_coils)

I believe that your issue may be one of terminology ("discrete OUTPUTS" vs coils). If that is not the case please edit your question to show how you are changing the status of the LED and, perhaps, a circuit diagram (things become more complicated when step relays are used).

Comment: I think it is a case of nomenclature.  I didn't realize a discrete output is actually considered a 'coil'.  I'll have to do some testing reading coils and post back here.